# how to fill excel sheet data in android studio and fetch date wise data in sheet format of given app

Tags: java, excel, android-studio

how to fill excel sheet data in android studio and fetch date wise data in one click button show excel on this user

- daily
- Monthly
- yearly data show in our application

wise data in sheet format of given app

excel sheet given and store data 
and fetch data to date wise on this excel sheet

i want to send data on firebase date wise and store data in one of the excel sheet whenever customer select date on date picker like  21/01/2019  to  21/02/2019 then one month data show that user so please co-operate with me bcz last 2 month i am searching this questions answer.

Comment: If you have to create some Excel file in Android you should use som API. There are some. You just have to find one that fits your needs

Comment: thank you so much Fabio sir  for response this question i am try this

Comment: please tell me how to configure our app anD provide api link